# Is it “My cat in bed” or “My cat on bed”?

Tags: differences, prepositions

I had a discussion with my friends few days back regarding prepositions:
 **On** and **In** for this picture.

[image: cat napping in/on a small toy bed]

I  argued saying

> My cat is **on** bed.

but my friend corrected me saying, it is

> My cat is **in** bed.

I am confused, which one is correct?!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It is not clear what you are asking— what is the scenario you are trying to describe? *On the bed*, *in the bed*, and *in bed* are all valid, but have different meanings. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may also be of interest.

Comment: Of course, one could always say "My cat is abed."

Answer (score 2):

To say: *My cat is on my bed*

means that the cat is on top of the bed and not under the bed-clothes.

To say: *My cat is in my bed*

indicates that the cat is under the bed-clothes.

This holds true for other creatures.

However, when it comes to people, we say that someone is *in bed*, indicating beneath sheets/blankets - as opposed to *in the bed*, unless we are talking about a specific bed.

Comment: But a human can also be laying ON the bed.  This tends to imply being atop the bedclothes, but could go either way.

Comment: @Hot Licks As it is now 01.15 in my part of the world, I am about to decide the issue.

Comment: @HotLicks - Is this human going to lay an egg on the bed?  *Lying*, please!

Comment: @aparente001 Or getting laid.

Comment: @aparente001 - I was not lying!!

Comment: @HotLicks - I don't get it. "A human laying ... on the bed" is a misuse of "lay" that is extremely common where I live, in place of "lying."  But "lay" (except as a past tense of "lie," which is totally different) takes an object.

Comment: @aparente001 - Why are you accusing me of being untruthful?  [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lie) *lay has been used intransitively in the sense of “lie” (lay down for a quick nap) since the 14th century. The practice was unremarked until around 1770; attempts to correct it have been a fixture of schoolbooks ever since. Generations of teachers and critics have succeeded in taming most literary and learned writing, but intransitive lay persists in familiar speech and is a bit more common in general prose than one might suspect.*

Comment: @HotLicks - I'm not accusing you of being untruthful.  I know you like to be playful with words. // I am aware, as I wrote, that "intransitive lay persists in familiar speech and is a bit more common in general prose than one might suspect."  I would need a little more documentation than that to change my mind.

Comment: Consider:  Why is "Now I lay me down to sleep" perfectly fine, but "Now I lay down to sleep" is not?

Answer (score 1):

> Linda is already **in** bed.

This means she has taken off her clothes, brushed her teeth, and gotten under the sheets.

> "Where is Linda?"
>   "She's **on** **the** bed."

This means that if you look at the bed, you'll see Linda lying or sitting or jumping up and down on top of the bed.

> "Put Linda **to** bed."

This means undress her, give her a bath, brush her teeth for her, and stick her under the sheets.

> Get those kids back **into** bed.

They were already in bed, but now, suddenly, they're all over the house, yelling and screaming and stuffing their faces with ice cream.

Note that anything that pertains to a person or object that is *not* covered by a sheet requires a definite article.